# how to pass authorization token in header in php

Tags: php, web-services

i am trying to pass the authorization token in my php page.
The code i am using is as below:

```
function getValues(){

    $path='webservice path';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic token_no'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'));

    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $retValue;

}
```

but i am not able to include the header.
Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: What is the problem? What errors are you getting? What are you expecting to get? What is the authorization value (`Basic token_no` will cause errors)? Please put together a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753195/php-curl-header

Comment: Actually i am getting 401 error for web service call

Comment: I think authorztn code is not getting added to the header

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044315/how-to-set-the-authorization-header-using-curl) out

Answer (score 1):

You should only set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` once, with an array containing all headers.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
         'Authorization: Basic token_no',
         'Content-type: text/xml',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
    ));
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Remember `token_no` has to be a base64 encoded token. Are you certain that the headers are your issue? You can test that headers are being set by firing off the same request to a local URL, and logging the headers.